# Android SDK and Eclipse, shows different installed platforms?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open **C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe** it shows me that I **have installed**

*Tools*

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools

*Android 2.2 (API 8)*

- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- Google APIs

---

When I open **Eclipse** and click on the **"Android SDK Manager"** button it shows that Ive installed

*Tools*

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools

*Android 4.0.3 (API 15)*

- Documentation for Android SDK
- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Google APIs
- Sources for Android

*Android 2.1 (API 7)*

- Documentation for Android SDK
- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- Google APIs

*Extras*

- Google USB Driver

---

**Why does it show different packages and wich one should I use?**

Comment: Because they are using different SDK installations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably because Eclipse is using a different Android SDK location than `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`. Take a look at Preferences > Android > SDK Location field to see what Eclipse is using.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Windows Menu, Click on Preference Option and in the Dialogbox left side there is second option called "Android", click on it & check that your SDK directory is same as you are view from C: or some other.

Comment: hey , was the solution useful for you ?